# Necesito terminar con el bucle while en este pequeño código

Tags: python

Estoy creando un pequeño programa de login, que te pide nombre de usuario. Y, como todos sabemos, en muchas ocasiones el usuario puede introducir su numero o nombre de usuario incorrecto.
Tengo este pequeño trozo de código. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el `while` no repita infinitamente?

```
self.op=input("¿Quiere acceder a su cuenta con su nombre de usuario o con su dirección de correo electrónico?")

        if self.op == "Nombre de usuario" or self.op == "nombre de usuario" or self.op == "NOMBRE USUARIO":
            self.nombreUsuario=input("Introduce nombre de usuario")
            if self.nombreUsuario == self.nombreUsuario1:
                print("Usuario correcto")
            elif self.nombreUsuario != self.nombreUsuario1:
                a=input("Usuario incorrecto.\n Vuelva a introducir su nombre de usuario")
                while a != self.nombreUsuario1:
                    print("Usuario incorrecto\nVuelva a introducir su nombre de usuario")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para salir de un ciclo `while` que hace uso de una variable de control debes modificar el valor al que apunta dicha variable dentro del propio `while`, para dar la oportunidad de hacer falsa la condición del ciclo en algún momento. En caso contrario tendrás un ciclo infinito, dado que la condición será siempre verdadera una vez iniciado el ciclo.

En tu caso, basta con algo así:

```
self.op = input("¿Quiere acceder a su cuenta con su nombre de usuario o con su dirección de correo electrónico?")

if self.op.lower() == "nombre de usuario":
    nombre_usuario = input("Introduce nombre de usuario: ")
    while nombre_usuario != self.nombreUsuario1:
        nombre_usuario = input(("Usuario incorrecto.\n"
                                "Vuelva a introducir su nombre de usuario: "))
    self.nombreUsuario = nombre_usuario
    print("Usuario correcto")
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboración!